# how do i connect a c program to mysql?

Tags: mysql, c

This is my c program which connects to database called (add_tbl). Now my query is where am i supposed to mention the database name. without that how will it connect to the database and store the result?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

typedef struct
{
    char host[20];
    char user[25];
    char pass[50];
}DB_CONN_PARAMS;

int main()
{
    MYSQL *db;
    char query_str[150];
    int num1, num2, q_status;
    DB_CONN_PARAMS *params = calloc(1,sizeof(DB_CONN_PARAMS));
    params->host = "127.0.0.1";
    params->user = "root";
    params->pass = "Password";
    MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params);
    db = connect_db(params);
    free(params);
    //get numbers
    scanf("%d %d", num1, num2);

    //insert num1, num2 and sum into query string
    printf(query_str,"INSERT INTO add_tbl (num1, num2, sum) VALUES (%d,%d %d);",
           num1,num2,(num1 + num2));

    //run the query
    q_status = mysql_query(db, query_str);
    if (q_status)
    {        //insert failed
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute \"%s\"\n%s\n", query_str, mysql_error(db));
        mysql_close(db);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Insert successful:\nQuery used: \"%s\"\n", query_str);
    mysql_close(db);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

my database table name is 'add_tbl'
where to specify the database name.I am not able to understand it.Please somebody guide me.

Comment: After editing this, I noticed one problem immediately, this: `(%d,%d %d)` should be this: `(%d,%d,%d)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `connect_db()` does, but you are supposed to use [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html). There you can set the database as parameter `db`.

If you later want to change the default database, you can do that with [`mysql_select_db()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-select-db.html).

BTW, instead of doing

```
DB_CONN_PARAMS *params = calloc(1,sizeof(DB_CONN_PARAMS));
params->host = "127.0.0.1";
params->user = "root";
params->pass = "Password";
MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params);
db = connect_db(params);
free(params);
```

you might want to change it (for simplicity) to

```
DB_CONN_PARAMS params = {};
params.host = "127.0.0.1";
params.user = "root";
params.pass = "Password";
// MYSQL * connect_db(DB_CONN_PARAMS *params); // omit that here, it belongs either to the header or above the current function
db = connect_db(&params);
```

or even

```
DB_CONN_PARAMS params = { .host = "127.0.0.1", .user = "root", .pass = "Password" };
db = connect_db(&params);
```